# Leave blank lines in expl3 packages for better code clarity

Tags: expl3, best-practices, package-writing

Leaving empty lines in the code of a package is usually not recommended. But for packages written with `expl3` new lines, as spaces, are ignored.

So, could blank lines be safety used to aerate the code of a package and improve its clarity ?

If yes, is it a good practice ?

Comment: yes and yes allowing white space to lay out the code without affecting the behaviour is a major aim of the expl3 conventions

Comment: Many LaTeX packages are written in `.dtx` format, where the code is separated bout by comments - so in these cases, at least, blank lines are not normally present